# Como limpar um formulário depois de enviar os dados?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Criei uma função em javascript para limpar e chamei no botão que enviar com onclick. ficou assim:

```js
function limpar(){
  $("input").val("");
  $("textarea").val("");
 }
```

```html
<input type=text>

<textarea></textarea>

<button type="submit" onclick="limpar()">Enviar Mensagem</button>
```

Está apagando, o problema é que apaga antes de enviar. Eu preciso que ele apague depois do envio.
Obs: Criei um php para enviar e no formulário de modo que envie e fique na mesma tela, sem recarregar a página.

Preciso de ajuda urgente!

Comment: precisa colocar o formulario completo e o php também pra entender melhor seu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar setInterval como sugerido ou então no lugar de executar `limpar()` no clique do botão, executar essa função no submit do form:

```
$(document).on('submit','#ID_DO_FORM',function(){
    $("input").val("");
    $("textarea").val("");
});
```

Você precisa trocar #ID_DO_FORM, pelo id do formulário.

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar a função `setInterval`.
Ex:

```
setInterval(function(){ $("input").val("");
    $("textarea").val(""); }, 3000);
```

Essa função será executada depois de 3 segundos após clicares no botão.

Comment: Deu certo Assim, Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#IdForm").submit(function(){

     // seu codigo aqui

     $(this).reset(); // função de resetar form
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a todos! consegui solucionar o problema através da resposta do Francisco. Sobretudo agradeço pela colaboração de todos.